# DB Backup to Azure url - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, azure

[image]

[image]I'm attempting to backup my database to Azure url from SQL Server 2014.

When I do so I get this error talked about in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/nonrecoverable-io-error-backup-url

However, I've checked the storage type or kind and it is general purpose and still receive this error. Any other reasons this would occur?

Comment: Can you show us any screenshots about how you set the backup?

Comment: I've added the images above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the Azure tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15.

If the error still exist, I would suggest you update your SQL Server to 2016 or later version. Try this way: [Quickstart: SQL backup and restore to Azure Blob storage service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=SSMS).

HTH.

Comment: I have followed the first tutorial thoroughly and others as well.  To update to a later version would be too expensive at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with SQL Server 2014, you need to provision a General Purpose V1 Storage account, not V2. It should work then.